# Статический конструктор структуры и инициализация синглтона

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, шаблон-одиночка

Вопрос на основе двух статей:

- [О синглтонах и статических конструкторах](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2011/08/blog-post.html)
- [Реализация синглтонов в .NET: Field-like vs. Lazy](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2016/12/singleton-implementation-in-net-field.html)

Собственно, вспомнил, что у структур несколько иначе обстоят дела с вызовом статического конструктора (он вызывается перед обращением к статическому полю, но не вызывается при создании инстанса структуры). Соответственно, возникло желание поместить свойство `Instance` внутрь структуры. Сначала я хотел что-то намудрить с красотой обращения к нему, но потом передумал и решил спросить по самому концепту - даёт ли это что-то помимо ленивой инициализации (кстати, а действительно ли она тут гарантирована) и есть ли какие-то побочные эффекты?.

http://ideone.com/BrgjAI

```
using System;

struct FieldLikeSingletonWrapper
{
    public class FieldLikeSingleton
    {
        internal FieldLikeSingleton()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FieldLikeSingleton.ctor");
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }       
    }

    public static FieldLikeSingleton Instance { get; } = new FieldLikeSingleton();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Main()");

        if (args.Length == 42)
        {
            FieldLikeSingletonWrapper.Instance.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати, сначала мне казалось очевидным, что сделать сам синглтон структурой - идея ужасная, поскольку структура будет копироваться. Но потом я подумал, что можно объявить прокинуть методы через структуру (да, это минус), но использовать скрытый вложенный класс:

http://ideone.com/Ok1XP0

```
using System;

struct FieldLikeSingleton
{
    private class FieldLikeSingletonImpl
    {
        internal FieldLikeSingletonImpl()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FieldLikeSingleton.ctor");
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }       
    }

    private static FieldLikeSingletonImpl instance = new FieldLikeSingletonImpl(); 
    public static FieldLikeSingleton Instance { get; }

    public void Foo()
    {
        instance.Foo();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Main()");

        if (args.Length == 42)
        {
            FieldLikeSingleton.Instance.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Какие плюсы и минусы есть у этих подходов по сравнению с обычным field-like?

Comment: _у структур несколько иначе обстоят дела с вызовом статического конструктора_ -- а как?

Comment: @VladD, у них статический конструктор вызывается перед обращением к статическому полю. Но не вызывается при создании инстанса структуры :)

Comment: @Qwertiy а можете добавить это (про статический конструктор) в вопрос, а то это нетривиально?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, добавил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> вспомнил, что у структур несколько иначе обстоят дела с вызовом статического конструктора (он вызывается перед обращением к статическому полю, но не вызывается при создании инстанса структуры).

Это не совсем так. Точнее, это так, если считать, что `default(T)` - это единственный способ создания экземпляра структуры. Да, в случае `var x = new FooStruct()` статический конструктор не вызывается, поскольку в этом случае происходит просто выделение и обнуление блока памяти. Если бы в этом случае была проверка инициализации типа, то это привело бы к существенным накладным расходам во время исполнения (а ведь структуры предназначены именно для таких low-level сценариев, где каждый такт имеет значение).

Аналогично, при копировании структуры статический конструктор не будет вызван:

```
var @default = new FooStruct(); // нет вызова статического конструктора
var copy = @default; // нет вызова статического конструктора
```

Однако при вызове пользовательского конструктора структуры, статический конструктор будет вызван (это же будет справедливым и для пользовательского конструктора по-умолчанию; его нельзя создать в C#, но если создадите, то статический конструктор будет вызываться и для `var x = new FooStruct()`):

```
var instance = new FooStruct(42);
```

Вообще, тут нужно понять, какую именно проблему вы хотите решить.

Если вопрос с ленивостью инициализации синглтона, то наличие поля `Instance` во вложенном классе сделает поведение полностью ленивым:

```
class SomeSingleton
{
  private class SingletonHolder
  {
    public static readonly SomeSingleton Instance = new SomeSingleton();
  }

  public static SomeSingleton Instance => SingletonHolder.Instance;
}
```

В этом случае обращение к статическим членам класса `SomeSingleton` не приведет к инициализации синглтона. Единственный способ инициализации синглтона - обращение к свойству `Instance`.

Подчеркну: это решение полностью ленивое, но оно страдает остальными проблемами field-like синглтонов, связанных с исключениями.

P.S. Ну и все танцы с бубном по делегированию структуре - вещь просто избыточная: она серьезно усложняет сопровождение без каких-либо выгод с точки зрения времени исполнения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, что-то я не подумал, что класс себя поведёт так же. А в чём усложнение со структурой по сравнению с классом? Выглядит, что они совершенно одинаковые. И неужели нет каких-то ещё бонусов или подводных камней от структур?

Comment: У делегации для каждого метода усложнение в том, что для каждого метода синглтона нужно создать метод в оболочке.
Второе усложнение - концептуальное: стркутуры - должны обладать семантикой значения. Здесь этой семантики нет. Накладные расходы на копию возможны; накладные расходы на комментарии, объясняющие причину (неясную) использования структуры - тоже.

Comment: С делегацией понятно - но у класса тот же минус. Накладные расходы на копию - не понял, копию чего? У неё же полей нет, т. е. она не будет занимать больше, чем ссылка. Скорее даже меньше. Ну и с семантикой да - несколько нелогично получается.

Comment: Да, накладных расходов на копию не будет (хотя, по идее, размер структуры все равно не 0), но будут расходы на дополнительный уровень косвенности. Например, если без делегации что-то могло быть заинлайнено, то теперь оно не будет заинлайнено.

У класса без делегации минусов нет, поскольку приведенный мною код будет таким же, не зависимо от количества членов у синглтона.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, можешь [посмотреть вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615736/186999)?

Comment: @Grundy Ответил!