# Можно ли обойтись без статического конструктора?

Tags: c#, .net

Мне понятно, что статический конструктор служит для присвоения значений статическим переменным, что он вызывается в первую очередь при создании объекта класса.

Но зачем он нужен, если я могу присвоить эти значения при объявлении переменных?

Comment: Скорее всего, присвоение переменных на месте объявления — это синтаксический сахар, а сами присвоения реально делаются именно в статическом конструкторе.

Comment: а что значит _обойтись без статического конструктора_? не объявлять его вручную? или чтобы .NET его не создавал?

Comment: не объявлять вручную, а просто присвоить статической переменной значение в момент ее объявления.

Comment: @nikola, да, его можно не писать, и присваивать значения при объявлении - это будет то же самое

Comment: @nikola, а эсли на момент оьявления значение переменной тебе неизвестно? и оно приходит с какогото другого сайта, например или БД? тогда только статический конструктор

Comment: @Volodymyr какая связь?

Comment: @nikola Посмотрите в сторону паттерна Singleton, хорошая альтернатива статическим классам, если вам надо уменьшить время запуска.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov, статический конструктор есть у любого класса, не только статического

Comment: @Grundy, а, вот о чем речь.

Comment: @Grundy, _"статический конструктор есть у любого класса"_ - что-то сомневаюсь.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Не сомневайся :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy, хотя действительно похоже не во всех, а в тех где есть статические поля :)

Comment: @Grundy, я тут ответ накопипастил...

Comment: @Qwertiy, автор статей тоже участник ruSO :)

Comment: @Grundy, я знаю. Хочешь его позвать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, было бы не плохо :) но его что-то давно не видно

Comment: @Grundy, ну тогда зови))) Если напишет то же, что я накопипастил, удалю свой ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51931/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В языке C# существует несколько способов инициализации полей:

1. В месте объявления
2. В конструкторе

Вот наивный пример:

```
class Foo 
{
  private string s1 = "s1";
  private string s2;

  private static string s3 = "s3";
  private static string s4;

  public Foo()
  {
    s2 = "s2";
  }

  static Foo()
  {
    s4 = "s4";
  }
}
```

Если смотреть с высоты птичьего полета, то инициализация по месту реализуется довольно просто: выражение, использованое для инициализации поля переносится в соответствующий конструктор - в экземплярный конструктор для экземплярны полей и в статический конструктор для статических полей.

Тут нужно сказать, почему у нас два конструктора. Конструктор экземпляра - это некоторая вспомогательная функция, призванная инициализировать экземпляр создаваемого объекта. Например, мы можем сказать, что любой валидный объект должен обладать некоторым поведением (инвариантом) и конструктор - это специальная функция, обязанная его обеспечить. Инвариантом может быть что угодно: начиная от того, что некоторое поле не нулевое, заканчивая более сложными правилами, например, что сумма полей `дебет` и `кредит` равна 0.

Помимо инвариантов объектов существуют еще и инварианты типа: т.е. некоторые условия, которые должны быть верными не для конкретных объектов, но для типа целиком. Поведение типа выражается с помощью статических членов, а значит "инвариант" типа - это валидное состояние статичесих переменных, ответственность за валидность которых обеспечивает статический конструктор.

В отличие от конструктора объекта конструктор типа не вызывается пользователем. Вместо этого, он вызывается CLR в момент первого обращения к типу (опустим точные правила).

Существует тонкие различия в поведении во время исполнения, которое отличает использование инициализатора полей в месте объявления от инициализации этих же полей в конструкторе. *Инициализаторы статических и экземплярных полей - это синтаксический сахар, но очень важно знать, какой именно!*

## Разница в случае экземплярных полей и конструкторов

Все инициализаторы экземплярных полей перемещаются компилятором C# в экземплярных конструктор. Но главный вопрос здесь: куда именно.

В общих чертах конструктор экземпляра выглядит следующим образом:

```
// ctor
// Код инициализаторов полей
// Вызов конструктора базового класса
// Код текущего конструктора
```

У данного алгоритма есть два важных следствия. Во-первых, код инициализаторов экземплярных полей не просто помещается в конструктор, он помещается в самое его начало, еще *до вызова конструктора базового класса*, и во-вторых, *он будет скопирован во все экезмплярные конструкторы*.

Первое замечание очень важно (да, об этом могут спросить на собеседовании и это может пригодиться в реальных приложениях). Например, если кто-то вздумает вызвать виртуальный метод в конструкторе базового класса, то часть полей будет проинициализированы, а часть нет. Несложно догадаться, что поля, проинициализированные в месте объявления уже будут валидными, а другие поля будут содержать дефолтные значения.

Да, да, да, вызывать виртуальные методы в конструкторах базового класса - это плохо, но в реальность такое бывает и нужно понимать, что в этом случае будет в рантайме.

## Разница в случае статических полей и конструкторов

Со статическими конструкторами дела обстоят несколько сложнее и проще одновременно. С точки зрения наследования, способ инициализации статических полей никак не пересекается с вызовом статического конструктора базового класса. Никак. Там вообще процесс вызова статических конструкторов отличается от экземплярных. Например, при создании **экземпляра** наследника вначале вызывается статический конструктор наследника, а потом статический конструктор базового класса. А если дергается статический метод наследника, то статический конструктор базового класса вообще не вызовется автоматом (вызовется только если статический метод наследника как-то дернет базовый тип).

Но сложность возникает с тем, когда именно будет вызван статический конструктор.

Как уже написал @Qwertiy наличие или отсутствие статического конструктора в классе влияет на то, когда будет вызван этот самый конструктор. Наличие статического конструктора приводит к генерации странного специального флага, который затем скажет CLR, что можно более вольно относиться к времени вызова статического конструктора, и сделать это теперь можно будет не прямо перед первым обращением, а, например, перед вызовом метода, в котором это обращение происходит.

Потенциально, это может повлиять на эффективность приложения, поскольку теперь проверка будет делаться один раз, а не тысячи раз, при условии, что первое обращение находится в цикле от 0 до 1000.

## Заключение

Инциализатор полей (статических и нет) - это сахар, но он может быть с горчинкой, если не понимать, к чему приводит его чрезмерное использование.

Обычно я пользуюсь следующим эмпирическим правилом. Для экземплярных полей: нужно инициализировать поле аргументом конструктора - (без вариантов) использую конструктор; в противном случае - инициазатор полей. В случае статических полей: в подавляющем числе случаев использую инициализатор. Если кода много, то выделяю метод.

Если мне нужно использовать статический конструктор, чтобы задать порядок инициализации или изменить семантику инициализации типа, то я добавляю огромный комментарий, который говорит, почему к этому фрагменту кода нужно относитсья очень внимательно.

Если мне нужно использовать инициализатор для экземплярных полей, чтобы инициализация прошла до вызова конструктора базового класса, то я рефакторю код, чтобы этого было не нужно. Например, выделяю фабриный метод. Если же такоей поведение действительно нужно, то тут нужен двухстраничный комментарий, который объясняет почему это нужно и почему другие варианты не подходят.

Comment: небольшой побочный вопрос: статический конструктор есть у любого класса? либо только у тех, где есть статические поля например или описан вручную?

Comment: Вопрос-то побочный, но непростой. Мне кажется, что статического конструктора не будет, если нет статических переменных. А если бы и был, то его бы JIT выпилил-бы, если бы он был пустым.

Comment: Мне почему-то казалось, что где-то видел что он должен был быть у всех, но в тестовом примере действительно ildasm показал его только в тех классах, в которых статические поля есть

Comment: Ну, если речь о генерируемом статическом конструкторе на IL уровне, то проверить это легко. И судя по ILDASM-у он таки не генерируется. Могли быть тонкости на уровне CLR, но их раскопать будет чутка сложнее.

Comment: Привет! Не мог бы прояснить ситуацию с [этим вопросом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/642682/186999)?

Comment: @Grundy Ответил. Полностью не согласен с принятым там ответом:)

Answer (score 9):

Существует две гарантии вызова статических конструкторов:

- **Базовая гарантия инициализации типа:** конструктор типа будет вызван перед созданием экземпляра или перед первым обращением к статическому члену.
- **"Расслабленная" (relaxed) гарантия инициализация типа (BeforeFieldInit):** конструктор типа будет вызван при первом обращении к статическому полю (справедливо для .NET 4.0+) и может быть вызван когда угодно до первого обращения к типу.

Для того, чтобы CLR использовала «расслабленную» модель, тип должен быть помечен флагом BeforeFieldInit. Для языка C# выбор определяется наличием или отсутствием явного статического конструктора: при наличии явного статического конструктора используется базовая модель инициализации типа, а при отсутствии статического конструктора – расслабленная модель.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()
    { }

    private Singleton()
    { }

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }
}
```

Практика показывает, что в большинстве случаев при отсутствии явного конструктора, JIT-компилятор вызывает инициализатор статических переменных непосредственно перед вызовом метода, в котором используется эта переменная.

Если же использовать статический конструктор класса Singleton, то поведение будет именно таким, которое ожидает большинство разработчиков – инициализатор поля вызван не будет до первого обращения.

Источники:
http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2013/07/blog-post.html
http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2011/08/blog-post.html
http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2013/06/blog-post_28.html

Comment: _при запуске приложения на экране будет только одна строка: “Starting Main…”._ - похоже в коде чего-то не хватает.

Comment: @Grundy, исправил.

Comment: Я ответил, но твой ответ вполне валиден и полезен. Я специально не стал расписывать аспект, покрытый твоим ответом в деталях.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, тут вся информация из твоего блога - я ожидал, что ты захочешь её в своём ответе написать. Ну раз нет, то пусть остаётся :)

Answer (score 6):

Суть статического конструктора в том, что он вызывается один единственный раз и до создания первого элемента указанного типа. Вы конечно можете делать инициализацию каждый раз при создании экземпляра с дополнительной проверкой, но зачем?

> Но зачем он нужен, если я могу присвоить эти значения при объявлении переменных?

Он может быть полезен, если важен порядок инициализации статических полей или для выполнения каких-то дополнительных действий, которые не происходят при простой инициализации типа для которого используется статический член.

[Например](http://ideone.com/4PURl2):

```
using System;

class A {
    public A() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}

class B {
    public B() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}

public class Test
{
    static readonly A a;
    static readonly B b;

    public static void Main()
    {
    }

    static Test()
    {
        b = new B();
        Console.WriteLine("-");
        a = new A();        
    }

}
```

Т.о. мы изменили порядок создания статических полей и добавили выполнение дополнительного действия, чего нельзя было бы добиться при простой инициализации по месту.

Comment: Не очень понял, зачем инициализировать ее каждый раз, если я просто присваиваю значение статическому полю в момент его объявления? Вопрос в том, зачем мне создавать конструктор, если можно сразу же присвоить значение?

Comment: @nikola, alexolut, подумал что ты хочешь инициализировать поле не при объявлении, а в обычном кострукторе

Comment: @nikola да, Grundy правильно описал мои мысли. Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: @alexolut там ниже user2455111 говорит, что он генерируется автоматически компилятором при простом присвоении, это правда?

А про дополнительные действия и порядок инициализации не подумал. Спасибо!

Comment: @nikola согласно ответу Qwertiy, user2455111 не прав.

Comment: @alexolut, не совсем так, в MSIL статический конструктор будет, в ответе Qwertiy речь идет про результат JIT

Comment: @Grundy не совсем не прав, получается? :)

Comment: @nikola, да, статический конструктор генерируется. Но он генерируется не такой же, как если бы он был написан явно (флаг beforeFieldInit).

Comment: @nikola такое случается. Иногда даже отвечающий в процессе разбора узнает новые для себя детали.

Answer (score 6):

Не каждый объект можно инициализировать в одну строку. К примеру, часто используемый мною класс [`XmlSerializerNamespaces`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces(v=vs.110).aspx) требует после вызова конструктора несколько раз вызвать метод Add.

Или, если нужно построить делегат через Linq Expressions - приходится отдельно создавать параметры, хотя все остальное выражение обычно можно записать в одну строку.

Иногда требуется и более сложная логика инициализации.

---

Кроме того, надо понимать, что это в C# инициализаторы статических полей отличаются от статического конструктора. В процессе же компиляции они все попросту дописываются в его начало.

Comment: Мысль про дополнительные действия при инициализации ясна. Спасибо. То есть, если у меня инициализация в одну строку (присвоение значения или подобное), то можно обойтись без конструктора и это не будет дурным тоном, верно?

Comment: @nikola да, можно обойтись без статического конструктора **в коде на C#**. Кстати, дурным тоном будет как раз создавать статический конструктор там где справится инициализатор. В байт-коде же статический конструктор будет присутствовать в любом случае :)

Answer (score 2):

Если рассматривать статический класс как шаблон - то это "халявный" синглтон, и все статические члены класса - члены данного синглтона. При этом у данного статического класса при передаче ему экземпляра не статического класса будет полный доступ к полям этого не статического класса.

Статический класс также называют классом ТИПА (а статический конструктор конструктором типа соответственно), это значит что даже если класс объявлен не статическим, для него по факту будет создана статическая составляющая.

Ну а дальше надо исходить из удобства и необходимости:

"ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР" СТАТИЧЕСКОГО КЛАССА:
1. Нет наследования
2. Доступен везде без передачи какой либо ссылки в код функции (согласно области видимости)

ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР НЕ СТАТИЧЕСКОГО КЛАССА:
1. Есть наследование
2. Можно иметь несколько экземпляров
3. Доступен только по ссылке переданной в функцию

Answer (score 0):

К примеру у вас есть класс

```
internal class SomeType {
private static Int32 s_x = 5;
}
```

этот код будет равносильным коду

```
internal class SomeType {
private static Int32 s_x;
static SomeType() { s_x = 5; }
}
```

Если вы используете 1й вариант, то компилятор автоматически сгенерирует конструктор типа

Comment: Не совсем равносильно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему?

Comment: См. мой ответ и 3 статьи по ссылкам.

Comment: @Qwertiy я предполагал, что равносильным будет код, а не момент в который он исполняется. И кстати, попробовал ваш ответ привести к коду. Результаты получились следующие: При базовой гарантии переменной присваивоилось значение в начале выполнения метода статического метода Main (или же при выполнении конструктора класса, в котором будет использоваться переменная), при расслабленной - при инициализации класса, перед выполнением метода (использующего переменую), перед обращением к переменной