# Почему MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes игнорирует наследование

Tags: c#, рефлексия, атрибуты

Метод [`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) получает список атрибутов члена типа. Вторым параметром он принимает логический флаг, который при значении `true` позволяет получить список атрибутов с учётом всей цепочки наследования.

Однако, в описании метода и на MSDN упоминается следующее поведение:

> This method ignores the inherit parameter for properties and events. To search the inheritance chain for attributes on properties and events, use the appropriate overloads of the [`Attribute.GetCustomAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1375e30.aspx) method.

То есть для `PropertyInfo` и `EventInfo` логический флаг игнорируется, всегда возвращаются только атрибуты без учёта цепочки наследования.

Чем обусловлено такое поведение?

Comment: Там достаточно ясно написано: *This parameter is ignored for properties and events*, то есть свойства и события игнорируются. Думаю, что данный вопрос нужно адресовать разработчикам из `Microsoft`, которые писали этот метод.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, ну так вопрос как раз и _почему_ для свойств и событий игнорирование происходит

Comment: @DenisBubnov, точно так же ясно это написано и в моём вопросе ниже цитаты. Думаю, сообщество вполне может быть в курсе, а если и нет, то, возможно, у кого-то есть предположения. На большом SO такие вопросы задаются регулярно.

Comment: @Grundy, это написано в документации на MSDN, в документации к методу, который написали разработчики `Microsoft`, мы с Вами можем только предполагать и гадать, почему так.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, это вопрос, который имеет чёткий определённый ответ, это не вопрос, который направлен на получение субъективного мнения ("какой язык программирования самый лучший?"). Даже возможные ответы-предположения в любом случае должны быть основаны на технических знаниях, а не предпочтениях.

Comment: @DenisBubnov. [Вопросы в духе “Почему разработчики языка/библиотеки сделали так?”](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3522/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, да, вижу, что можно. Но даже ответы, приведенные здесь - будут предположением (мнением, основанным на знаниях), так как все же есть разработчики, которые это написали ))) Поэтому принимать ответ, основанный на мнении - все равно, что принять неверный ответ. Вот к чему я клоню. Вас понял, вопросов больше нет. Почитаю ответы, которые будут опубликованы, интересно мнение окружающих относительно вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не согласен с ответом Павла.

Во-первых, свойства - это лишь синтаксический сахар вокруг методов + дополнительные метаданные. И я что-то не помню, чтобы там было какое-то фундаментальное отличие на уровне CLR от методов (если есть, то пруф в студию, буду очень рад узнать что-то новое).

Во-вторых, достаточно посмотреть реализацию [`MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodinfo.cs,c88a99be2bd2a319). Там будет видно, что вся работа выполняется в методе [`CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/customattribute.cs,9f7d68e174e7a316) в котором проверяется значение параметра `inherit` и если он `true`, то идет анализ атрибутов базового класса.

Теперь, посмотрите на метод расширения [`CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/attribute.cs,992312cfe5ea1609). Этот метод, в отличие от экземплярного метода `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttribute` не имеет никаких ограничений для свойств и просто дергает метод [`CustomAttributeExtensions.InternalGetCustomAttribute`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/attribute.cs,3d8434dd0e931415) который, как и в случае с атрибутами метода ранее, просто проходит иерархи наследования вручную.

Теперь, к исходному вопросу: почему `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes` не работает для свойств? Я думаю, что кто-то изначально допустил ошибку, а такие ошибки нельзя исправить не сломав существующих клиентов. Вот и пришлось потом добавлять методы расширения, которые исправили ситуацию и позволили вернуть функционал, пропущенный изначально.

А насчет CLR... Не правда это, кажется:))

Comment: а может быть все-таки был какой-то смысл сделать именно так, а не простая ошибка? Например, какая-нибудь оптимизация там?

Comment: @Grundy Я поузнаю у коллег, но, навскидку, я ничего такого не вижу. Все эти 'inherited' параметры - это же чистая надстройка. Там полностью вручную идет анализ иерархии наследования. Так что, возможно, в этом просто не было толком необходимости. Других причин пока не видно.

Comment: @downvoter: просто любопытно, в чем причина минуса?;)

Comment: У тебя же нет минуса

Comment: Не мог бы ответить на вопрос [Зачем нужен пустой делегат Action<T>?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/667101/186999) А то мнения разделились :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ простой: на уровне CLR свойства не переопределяются, а скрывают друг друга по имени. Если у вас есть виртуальное свойство в родителе и вы его переопределили в потомке - с точки зрения CLR это два разных свойства.