# Зачем нужен пустой делегат Action<T>

Tags: c#

Изучая лямбда выражения наткнулся на делегаты Action и Func. Зачем нужен второй я понял, хотя бы для :

```
Func<int, int, int> summ = (x, y) => x + y;
Console.WriteLine(summ(10,20));
```

Но для чего нужен пустой `Action<T>` непонятно.

Приведите простенький пример зачем он может понадобиться ? И почему нельзя поставить `void` в `Func<T, TResult>` и получить тот же самый `Action<T>` вида  `Func<int, void>` например?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58889/discussion-on-question-by------actiont).

Comment: Чтобы void не писать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Существует два мира - мир чистого функционального программирования и реальный.

В чистом мире чистого функционального программирования не существует изменяемого состояния и не существует операторов (statements), а все является выражением. В этом идеальном мире у функций нет побочных эффектов, а любая конструкция в языке программирования является выражением (т.е. возвращает результат).

Но в реальном мире - все по другому.

В реальном мире, а особенно в мире C#, есть побочные эффекты и есть замечательный тип `Void`, который является необычным типом, не совместимым с другими. В этом мире действие (`Action`) не может быть выражено через функцию (`Func`), просто потому, что `Func<T, void>` запрещен, а тип `Unit` (аналогичный типу `Void`, но приводимый к обобщенному типу `T`) отсутствует. Если бы это было не так, то следующий код был бы валиден:

```
Func<int, Unit> fun = n => System.Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Это не значит, что данное правило универсально для всех языков реального мира, и даже для мира .NET, но для C# - это так. Тот же F# (язык более близкий к математическому миру) имеет тип `Unit` и умеет автоматически конвертировать .NET-ый `Void` в `Unit`, что делает приведенный код валидным.

TL;DR; `Func<int, void>` запрещен по историческим причинам (что жалко), поскольку очень часто приходится городить конвертер, который преобразует `Func<T>`, в `Action` и отбросит результат.

Если же говорить о реальные сценарии, то с применимостью типов `Action` проблем никаких.

- `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach`: `Parallel.For(0, list.Count, n => Console.WriteLine(list[n]);`
- Похоже с предыдущим - `ActionBlock<T>` и действие, которое должно выполняться разумным числом потоков.
- `Task` и действие, которое должно быть выполнено асинхронно: `var task = Task.Run(() => SomeOperation());`
- Всяческие коллбеки для логгирования и прочих операций, которые ничего не возвращают.

В общем, наличие и популярность void-return функций определяет применимость `Action<T>`. По хорошему, нам стоит стараться свести побочные эффекты к разумному минимуму, но в реальном мире, этот минимум никогда не станет 0.